# Error with Bootstrap Carousel in Angular 4

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm getting an error in the console and couldn't get it to work. I'm currently using Angular 4 with Bootstrap.

My frontend developer is away this weekend and so couldn't get understand/find if there's any other file to add dependencies. What I know for a fact is that; in order to cut the homepage size, bootstrap JS functions are not added to the homepage.

This is the error in the first line:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'ngb-carousel' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngb-carousel' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-carousel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

Here's my home.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'angular-2-local-storage';
import { NgbCarouselConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { AuthService } from '../../core/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  providers: [NgbCarouselConfig]
})
export class HomeComponent {
  title = 'Resume - Homepage';
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    public localStorageService: LocalStorageService,
    config: NgbCarouselConfig,
  ) {
    config.interval = 5000;
    config.wrap = true;
    config.keyboard = false;
  }
}
```

While my HTML:

```
<ngb-carousel>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>First slide label</h3>
      <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
    </div>
    <img src="../../../assets/img/daddy.jpg"/>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Second slide label</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <img src="../../../assets/img/daddy.jpg"/>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

Comment: Did you import `NgbModule` in your module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you add `NgbModule` in  your app.module?

Something should be like this in app.module file import:

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

Comment: modules should  be registered in imports array not in declarations array